# mySQL caching - Memory or Hard disk?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, caching

I am working on a grid based treasure hunt like game in PHP , mySQL and I am trying to decide between two caching options.

**Game Description**
The user has a 1000 cell grid, clicking on some cells will have no effect, others will direct you to a "this item has been found!" page :)... many items are accessible via any of a number of touching cells (a group).

**Process**

When a user clicks on a cell I have a JS script that can detect which cell was clicked... it then either:

**Option 1:**
compares it to a comma separated list of 'item' cells from a memory cached mysql response. if the clicked cell is one of the 'item' cells it directs the user to an address like .../grid/cellnumber.php then if that cell number is part of a group (explained above in the game description) it redirects the user to the lowest cell number within the group which contains the "this item has been found!" page.

**or**

**Option 2:**
compares it to a multidimensional array containing group and cell number e.g item[group no, cell no] then if the cell clicked matches a cell no it directs the user to .../grid/group no.php

Option 2 is obviously neater but I think it requires roughly double the memory when its cached as it requires storing the cell and group number

what does everyone else think?

Comment: Memory wins every time on speed.

Comment: What does this have to do with caching? No mention is made anywhere of how a "hard disk" figures into the problem.

Comment: True, the "This Item has been found" page is cached to the hard disk as a php file but that is used in both options... its really a case of More memory cached (option 2 - the group and cell) or More HDD space used (Option one with the cell redirect pages).

Comment: Clean up your "question" please and mark the obvious question so we can answer them. Game development has nothing to do with it really. Instead please provide background etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to disk is measured in milliseconds, Access to Memory is measured in nanoseconds. Memory is much faster.

With a 1000 cell grid even if you have 1 MB of data in each cell it will still fit in the memory of a newer PC.